# Regex for string and must not contain a number at a certain position

Tags: regex, nginx

`forums/test.654654564/44654562356456-blabla.html`
I want to redirect this kind of URL...

I had this RegEx
`^\/forum\/.+\.([\d]+)\/([\d]+)-.+\.html$`

Unfortunately, the error that also handles this URL is
`forums/test.654654564/44654562356456-blabla.2332423233242.html`
This must not be allowed to happen. Any ideas?

The rule should be that as soon as the '.html' is preceded by `.\[\d+]` it should be ignored. is for an nginx redirect.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression required can be achieved by substituting the .+ in front of the .html bit with [a-zA-Z0-9] instead:

`^\/forums\/.+\.([\d]+)\/([\d]+)-[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.html$`

[image: regex test]